# Proper way to document and log brute force attacks when creating a user account

Tags: attacks, compliance, validation, account-security

We have the following use case:

Users can self register for a business account by filling a validation form with their ID, first name, last name, and DOB. ID is something that only the user knows ahead of time. Users have 5 attempts to match all of their information.

We are planning to maintain a couple of tables in a database in which we store the validation attempts:

```
Table 1 columns: id, attempts
Table 2 columns: id, fname, lname, dob
```

Table 1 and 2 have a one-many relationship. Here's an example of what happens if user tries to guess the firstname, last name and DOB 5 times before its locked. The application checks table 1's attempts column and if it's 5 or more than 5 for a specific ID, the user account (with that specific ID) is treated as locked.

```
table 1
id   attempts
1234  5

table 2
id    fname   lname  dob
1234  john     doe   19900101
1234  jane     doe   19900101
1234  jason    doe   19900101
1234  john     dae   20010102
1234  roger    smith 19960101
```

The problem with the above approach is that we are only tracking the failed attempts by ID. What if user tries to change the ID and attack? By keeping the first name, last name and DOB the same and guessing the ID?

Maybe I need to rethink the validation table design and my approach to solve the problem of user trying to guess ID? Or is there a better way to think about this problem?

Comment: If the id is really _something that only the user knows ahead of time_, then an attacker won't be trying to guess the name or dob. He will be trying to guess the secret (the id) for a given identity or identities (which he may be generating eg. from a given census). If an id can be guessed (such as being sequential), then you can't really that only the user knows it, and should change to randomly generated ones.

Comment: Do you tell your users what error they did?

Comment: @JuliePelletier We hide it as it might help the attacker.

Comment: @user1324816:  It is impossible to find a way to get all those details in 5 guesses.  Your only reason for worry is the fact that the hacker would find another way to get the user's details such as phishing or hacking their computer.